# jQuery - Get image from CSS using :after

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run the button animation where the checkboxes which have received the `.focus` state display their associated `background: url("x.svg");` as listed in the CSS.

The problem is with my markup. How do I get the `:after` to show on the label?

```js
$("input.cat-button").change(function() {
  $(this).addClass("button--animate");
  $(this).one(
    "webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend",
    function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass("button--animate");
    }
  );
  var t = $(this).closest("label");
  var btnColor = $(this).attr("data-color");
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    t.addClass("focus");
    t.css("background-color", btnColor);
    t.find("img").css("display", "none");
  } else {
    t.removeClass("focus");
    t.find("img").css("display", "flex");
    t.css("background-color", "");
    t.css("color", "");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2.3rem;
  display: flex;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  visibility: hidden
}

img {
  margin: 12px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

.focus {
  color: white;
  -webkit-animation-name: animate;
  animation-name: animate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 175ms;
  animation-duration: 175ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  curors: pointer !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.focus::after {
  padding-left: 15px;
  -webkit-animation: slideRight;
  animation: slideRight;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 375ms;
  animation-duration: 375ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

[data-rel="Animals"].focus:after {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/59f2a4cd1461940001901725_pp-animal(white).svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

[data-rel="Supplies"].focus:after {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ec71a7d43cde23a5c24d24f/5ec71a7d43cde2417524d2a4_pp-supplies(white).svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

[data-rel="Sports"].focus:after {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/5c9131911ad86f445cb5abc7_pp-sport(white).svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.99);
    transform: scale(0.99);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.99);
    transform: scale(0.99);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    padding-left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    padding-left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="category" for="animals">
  <input class="button cat-button chk loc-check" id="animals" value="animals" data-filter="Animals" data-color="green" data-rel="Animals" data-type="animals" data-section="other" data-target="buttons" type="checkbox">
    Animals
  <img class="button__icon" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/59f2492b831e8500015fa2c7_pp-animal.svg">
</label>

<label class="category" for="sports">
  <input class="button cat-button chk loc-check" id="sports" value="sports" data-filter="Sports" data-color="blue" data-rel="Sports" data-type="sports" data-section="other" data-target="buttons" type="checkbox">
    Sports
  <img class="button__icon" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/5c9131888de2c9e9a25fc894_pp-sport.svg">
</label>

<label class="category" for="supplies">
  <input class="button cat-button chk loc-check" id="supplies" value="supplies" data-filter="Supplies" data-color="orange" data-rel="Supplies" data-type="supplies" data-section="other" data-target="buttons" type="checkbox">
    Supplies
  <img class="button__icon" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ec71a7d43cde23a5c24d24f/5ec71a7d43cde28a6324d251_pp-supplies.svg">
</label>
```

Comment: Add the `focus` class to the `label` instead of the `input` and change your CSS accordingly?

Comment: The focus class is added to the label

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What is the issue here? Can you please elaborate it more.

Comment: The icon from the URL in the CSS is supposed to show on the labels :after when it's corresponding checkbox is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put data-rel attribute in lable instead of input element.

```js
$("input.cat-button").change(function() {
  $(this).addClass("button--animate");
  $(this).one(
    "webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend",
    function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass("button--animate");
    }
  );
  var t = $(this).closest("label");
  var btnColor = $(this).attr("data-color");
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    t.addClass("focus");
    t.css("background-color", btnColor);
    t.find("img").css("display", "none");
  } else {
    t.removeClass("focus");
    t.find("img").css("display", "flex");
    t.css("background-color", "");
    t.css("color", "");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2.3rem;
  display: flex;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  visibility: hidden
}

img {
  margin: 12px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

.focus {
  color: white;
  -webkit-animation-name: animate;
  animation-name: animate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 175ms;
  animation-duration: 175ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  curors: pointer !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.focus::after {
  padding-left: 15px;
  -webkit-animation: slideRight;
  animation: slideRight;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 375ms;
  animation-duration: 375ms;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

[data-rel="Animals"].focus:after {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/59f2a4cd1461940001901725_pp-animal(white).svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

[data-rel="Supplies"].focus:after {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ec71a7d43cde23a5c24d24f/5ec71a7d43cde2417524d2a4_pp-supplies(white).svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

[data-rel="Sports"].focus:after {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/5c9131911ad86f445cb5abc7_pp-sport(white).svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.99);
    transform: scale(0.99);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.99);
    transform: scale(0.99);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    padding-left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    padding-left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="category" for="animals" data-rel="Animals">
  <input class="button cat-button chk loc-check" id="animals" value="animals" data-filter="Animals" data-color="green" data-type="animals" data-section="other" data-target="buttons" type="checkbox">
  Animals
  <img class="button__icon" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/59f2492b831e8500015fa2c7_pp-animal.svg">
</label>
<label class="category" for="sports" data-rel="Sports">
  <input class="button cat-button chk loc-check" id="sports" value="sports" data-filter="Sports" data-color="blue" data-type="sports" data-section="other" data-target="buttons" type="checkbox">
  Sports
  <img class="button__icon" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/59df9e77ad9420000140eafe/5c9131888de2c9e9a25fc894_pp-sport.svg">
</label>
<label class="category" for="supplies" data-rel="Supplies">
  <input class="button cat-button chk loc-check" id="supplies" value="supplies" data-filter="Supplies" data-color="orange" data-type="supplies" data-section="other" data-target="buttons" type="checkbox">
  Supplies
  <img class="button__icon" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ec71a7d43cde23a5c24d24f/5ec71a7d43cde28a6324d251_pp-supplies.svg">
</label>
```